# C++ object file does not recompile when changes are made to a header file

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have a utility header file that has a bunch of inline functions. When I make a change the the body of the function and save it and remake it will recompile, but the new changes will not have taken effect, although my dependent files are listed in my Makefile.

I have tried compiling it as an object file, as a precompiled header. Many similar suggestions have said that the dependency structure is wrong, but as long as I have included it in the dependencies list for my target, and the header file has been touched more recently than the target has been generated it should recompile, correct?

```
run_tracker:    $(objects) run_tracker.o utils.h
                g++ -o $@ run_tracker.o $(objects) $(LIBS)
```

Say utils.h include a function like so:
void doSomething(){cout << "Doing Something" << endl;}

I have my run_tracker call the function, and then compile it like normal. It prints out "Do Something", I change that line to "Don't Do Something", make again,it does a shorter recompile, and then when I run it again, it prints the same thing as it did previously with no change.

Comment: This is the linker step. Whats your compilation rule for `run_tracker.o`?

Comment: I have this for that: %.o:   %.h

Comment: Then you need to add `utils.h` as depencency. And remove it from the linker rule, the linker doesn't depend on any header file.

Comment: I see. Is there an easy way to incorporate that into the %.o: %.h structure?

Comment: `%.o: %.h utils.h`.

Comment: When I add -MMD and -MP to my g++ command, the compiler generates a ".d" file, which contains a simple list of "target: dependency" ... sounds like you should inspect the .d file ... confirm that utils.h is there.

Comment: Note that Makefile uses time stamps, so check that your editor modifies the time stamp on the dependency file you edit.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by writing out the compilation step: run_tracker.o: run_tracker.cpp utils.h
g++ -c run_tracker.cpp $(INCS)
but is there a way to do this so you don't have to write out the compilation step for every file that uses this dependency?

Comment: The -MMD and -MP flags do not seem to generate .d files for me

Comment: Hmmm.  -MMD -MP are also new to me.  My command starts with "g++-7 std=c++17 ... and about 24 other options in front of  "-MMD -MP ", which is in front of the .cc source file.  Order is often important in Makefile.  I can't guess what your  $(objects) is doing as the first dependency, but since your "utils.h" does not generate an object, maybe this is a hint to investigate.

Comment: %.o: %.h utils.h Does not work for me.